# Log Logic Apps error messages to Azure storage file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have some steps in my logic apps eg Parse JSON.  If they fail, I can see the reason for the failure when I open the step in logic apps eg string instead of integer.
How can I log these error messages in my Azure storage account.
The dynamic content dialogue box doesn't specify error messages.
I have created a storage account, created files, populated them with a string and put them into the storage account.  I just need to get hold of the error message.
I will be processing JSON from HTTP requests.  If the JSON is invalid ie does not conform to the expected schema, I need the error logged, so people can query it with the provider of the data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I set up an array variable, put the Http request into a Scope and used the Result function like this.  result('Scope').  Then I used a Parse JSON step to parse the result.  Seems to work.  Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to log the runs error message, it is not necessary to be so troublesome. You could just use [outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#outputs) to implement it.

You set the `create blob` action run after `parse json` action fails, the blob content could be `outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors']`, if just want to get the error message it should be `outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors'][0]['message']`.

[image]